# Connect nginx with php-fpm in container

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I have problem with my server. I have installed NGINX, which work on port 80. I also have a php-fpm Docker container, now I need to use this php container in NGINX. How can I do this?

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
c15831d9576d        php:7.4-fpm         "docker-php-entrypoi…"   3 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds        0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp   php
```

My vhost

```
server {
            listen 80;
            root /var/www/html;
            server_name learn-linux.eu;
            index index.php;
            location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            }

            location ~* \.php$ {
              fastcgi_pass    193.33.111.185:9000;
              fastcgi_index index.php;
              fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
              #fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
              include fastcgi_params;
     }

}
```

Testing NGINX

```
nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

When I open my domain, I get

> 502 Bad gateway

My NGINX log

```
2020/09/22 21:02:44 [error] 2723228#2723228: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 185.140.255.82, server: learn-linux.eu, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://193.33.111.185:9000", host: "learn-linux.eu"
    
2020/09/22 21:03:46 [error] 2723228#2723228: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 185.140.255.82, server: learn-linux.eu, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://193.33.111.185:9000", host: "learn-linux.eu"
    
2020/09/22 21:03:47 [error] 2723228#2723228: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 185.140.255.82, server: learn-linux.eu, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://193.33.111.185:9000", host: "learn-linux.eu"
    
2020/09/22 21:03:47 [error] 2723228#2723228: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 185.140.255.82, server: learn-linux.eu, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://193.33.111.185:9000", host: "learn-linux.eu"
```

I tried to set `php:9000`, `127.0.0.1:9000`, `193.33.111.185:9000` but it is still not working.

What I do wrong?

Comment: Does port 9000 accessible from host. Test it using `telnet 127.0.0.1 9000`. If it does not look here abot docker port mapping: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/

Comment: On to the question, then: are you sure both containers are in the same docker network?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Hi :) I have php on container, but nginx normally on server without container. No problem with php and nginx container. This is a work requirement that nginx is normally on the server and php-fpm in the container.

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev nginx is installed as native, php-fpm in docker container

Comment: @PawelC, does the port 9000 accessible from your host (where Nginx runs) ?

Comment: @PawelC have you tried `0.0.0.0:9000`?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε yes, but still not working

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev yes

Comment: @PawelC Have you found a solution for this?